# Ajax request not sent, wrong selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Edit: the discussion helped me to unrderstand that the problem comes from outside the script... thx everybody for the help!

Problem : when I click one of the four groups of rating stars, only the "knowledge" one gets sent. I get the alert 'knowledge' and the controller function rateKnowledge gets reached. 
What's missing to make the 3 other rating groups work ??
I've spent hours searching but I'm sooo bad in javascript...
Should I write it a different way?

HTML :

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12" id="content">

            <div class="">
                <h2>Evaluate me</h2>
                <div class="hidden" id="content_type">{{$content_type}}</div>
                <div class="hidden" id="id">{{$id}}</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h3>SAVOIR</h3>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['\Modules\Course\Http\Controllers\Rating\RatingController@rateKnowledge']]) !!}
                        <fieldset class="rating">
                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating_knowledge" value="5"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating_knowledge" value="4"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating_knowledge" value="3"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star3" title="Good - 3 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating_knowledge" value="2"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star2" title="Could be better - 2 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating_knowledge" value="1"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star1" title="Disappointing - 1 star"></label>
                        </fieldset>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h3>PEDAGOGIE</h3>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['\Modules\Course\Http\Controllers\Rating\RatingController@ratePedagogics']]) !!}
                        <fieldset class="rating">
                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating_pedagogics" value="5"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating_pedagogics" value="4"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating_pedagogics" value="3"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star3" title="Good - 3 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating_pedagogics" value="2"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star2" title="Could be better - 2 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating_pedagogics" value="1"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star1" title="Disappointing - 1 star"></label>
                        </fieldset>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h3>SYMPATHIE</h3>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['\Modules\Course\Http\Controllers\Rating\RatingController@rateNiceness']]) !!}
                        <fieldset class="rating">
                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating_niceness" value="5"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating_niceness" value="4"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating_niceness" value="3"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star3" title="Good - 3 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating_niceness" value="2"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star2" title="Could be better - 2 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating_niceness" value="1"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star1" title="Disappointing - 1 star"></label>
                        </fieldset>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h3>ORGANISATION</h3>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['\Modules\Course\Http\Controllers\Rating\RatingController@rateOrganization']]) !!}
                        <fieldset class="rating">
                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating_organization" value="5"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating_organization" value="4"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating_organization" value="3"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star3" title="Good - 3 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating_organization" value="2"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star2" title="Could be better - 2 stars"></label>

                            <input class="rating-star" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating_organization" value="1"/>
                            <label class="full" for="star1" title="Disappointing - 1 star"></label>
                        </fieldset>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3>Bannir</h3>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['\Modules\Course\Http\Controllers\Rating\RatingController@ban']]) !!}
                        {{--<fieldset class="" id="ban">--}}
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <input class="" type="radio" id="ban" name="ban" value="true"/></span>
                        <label class="full" for="ban" title="Ban">Ce contenu n'a pas sa place ici (spam, contenu inapproprié)</label>
                        {{--</fieldset>--}}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
<script defer data-turbolinks-eval="false">
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var content_type = jQuery("#content_type").html();
            var id = jQuery("#id").html();

            function ajaxRequest(radioName,url) {
                var radioChecked = jQuery('input:radio[name='+radioName+']:checked');
                var rating = radioChecked.val();
                console.log("in_ajax",radioName,url,radioChecked);

                jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                    headers:{
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*",
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN':jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type : 'GET',
                    data: {
                        content_type:content_type,
                        id:id,
                        rating:rating
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('Success:',url);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log('Error:', xhr.status + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });

            }

            jQuery('input:radio[name=rating_knowledge]').click(function() {
                alert('knowledge');
                var radioName = "rating_knowledge";
                var url = "{!! route('rateKnowledge') !!}";
                console.log(radioName,url);
                ajaxRequest(radioName,url);
            });

            jQuery('input:radio[name=rating_pedagogics]').click(function() {
                alert('pedago');
                var radioName = "rating_pedagogics";
                var url = "{!! route('ratePedagogics') !!}";
                console.log(radioName,url);
                ajaxRequest(radioName,url);
            });

            jQuery('input:radio[name=rating_niceness]').click(function() {
                alert('niceness');
                var radioName = "rating_niceness";
                var url = "{!! route('rateNiceness') !!}";
                console.log(radioName,url);
                ajaxRequest(radioName,url);
            });

                jQuery('input:radio[name=rating_organization]').click(function() {
                alert('organization');
                var radioName = "rating_organization";
                var url = "{!! route('rateOrganization') !!}";
                console.log(radioName,url);
                ajaxRequest(radioName,url);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that's sent from the server, not the client. Why are you setting that in`ajaxSetup()`?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that would cause the problem. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: in fact, setting such a header will guarantee a CORS preflight, which the API may not expect and therefore may cause failure

Comment: `jQuery = window.jQuery;` is redundant ... perhaps you meant `var jQuery = window.jQuery;`

Comment: So the logic for the click handlers other than knowledge do or do not alert/console as expected?  EDIT: you are repeating ids for your labels though.  Ids cannot repeat.

Comment: @Barmar no error in the console. It says :
rating_knowledge http://localhost:8000/fr/course/ratings/rateKnowledge
rem-aut-numquam-cupiditate:325 in_ajax rating_knowledge http://localhost:8000/fr/course/ratings/rateKnowledge [input#star5.rating-star, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "input:radio[name=rating_knowledge]:checked"]
rem-aut-numquam-cupiditate:343 Success: http://localhost:8000/fr/course/ratings/rateKnowledge

Comment: Your javascript looks okay. I think your problem is in the Form::open method. Can you have a look at your compiled code in the browser and see what your form tags look like? Maybe post them here so we can see them, if they don't make the error obvious?

Comment: Also, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338237/laravel-4-multiple-forms-on-same-page

Comment: @LeoFarmer, the rendered form looks ok:  
`<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/fr/course/ratings/ratePedagogics" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="1BuyPuCI6kIyIJ0ZlwrMZWVs9QF6rCDrjg5B17MW">`  
  
And my routes are also ok I think:  
        Route::post('ratings/rateKnowledge',        ['as' => 'rateKnowledge', 'uses' => 'RatingController@rateKnowledge']);  
        Route::post('ratings/ratePedagogics',       ['as' => 'ratePedagogics', 'uses' => 'RatingController@ratePedagogics']);  
etc

Comment: @JaromandaX: I've tried, it didn't change anything

Comment: @Taplar: I've replaced the repeated ids by unique numbers, it didn't change anything. It's still only the rateKnowledge that gets selected and sent.

Comment: @StoryDrama - not sure what you are referring to in your remark to me because I don't think I actually suggested anything you should try!!?!

Comment: @StoryDrama You get those log messages even when you click on a different rating star? Or you get no log messages at all when you click on something other than `rating_knowledge`?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference, but if you're running all this code inside an event listener, there's probably no reason to wrap it inside `$(document).ready()` as well. The `turbolinks:load` event probably doesn't happen until well after the document is ready.

Comment: @JaromandaX you "suggested" to replace jQuery = window.jQuery by  
    var jQuery = window.jQuery;  
I did it, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Barmar yes, whatever rating star, 1-2-3-4-5 in rating_pedagogics, rating_niceness, rating_organization: all of them lead to the same action: alert rateKnowledge gets displayed, RatingController@rateKnowledge gets reached, I can dd() the result.   
  
I don't think turbolinks is the problem. It doesn't work without those 2 wrappers, and it works with. So the source of the problem is not there.  I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the fact that the radio input is never correctly selected. But how to correct that?

Comment: I don't sdee how this can be happening. You're clearly binding different handler functions to each radio name, yet for some reason when you click on any radio button it calls the handler for name=rating_knowledge.

Comment: That wasn't a solution that was redundant code

Comment: If I comment out the turbolinks:load (and add placeholder text for the compiled elements such as id) the links work and alert.

Comment: @LeoFarmer I've commented out the turbolinks:load, that didn't solve the problem. Could you get an alert of something else than rateKnowledge ??

Comment: Yes, I get all of them alerting. Is there more code that we don't see in your example?

Comment: @LeoFarmer yes, much more code and you are right the script works so the mistake is somewhere in the rest of my js scripts. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem. But rather than binding separate handlers for each radio button group, bind a single handler for all of them, and have it get the group name from `$(this)`.

```
$(".rating-star").click(function() {
    var radioName = this.name;
    var url = $(this).closest("fieldset").data("url");
    ajaxRequest(radioName, url);
});
```

I've moved the URL out of the Javascript and into the HTML, so it should be something like:

```
<fieldset class="rating" data-url="{!! route('rateKnowledge') !!}">
```

I don't use Laravel, I'm assuming this is possible.

Comment: thanks for trying but I've made the changes, which are perfectly ok with Laravel I think, and there is no change : it's still rateKnowledge that gets selected, I can console.log it, radioname always = rate_knowledge.

Comment: Can you make a stack snippet that shows the HTML and JS after Laravel has expanded all the macros, so we can execute it and see the problem?

Comment: yep I should have done that from the beginning...
https://jsfiddle.net/4h49jp6f/
  And what it shows is that: the script itself works, so there is something else in my javascript that is blocking it. I'll investigate ! Thank you for the help !